# Why does SQLite insert duplicate composite primary keys?

Tags: python, sqlite, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Code:

```
import sqlite3
c = sqlite3.Connection(':memory:')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE foo(a INTEGER, b VARCHAR(8), PRIMARY KEY(a, b))')
c.execute('INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES (1)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES (1)')
print(c.execute('SELECT * FROM foo').fetchall())
```

Output:

```
[(1, None), (1, None)]
```

Why is SQLite inserting rows with duplicate primary keys? How do I fix this?

Comment: In SQLite every `NULL` values are considered unique. So, composite attribute with one value set to `NULL` will always be considered as unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL PK (PRIMARY KEY) means UNIQUE NOT NULL. You shouldn't expect to be able to have a NULL in a value for a PK, let alone only one. You should declare PK columns NOT NULL and not put NULL in them.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#primkeyconst):

> Each row in a table with a primary key must have a unique combination of values in its primary key columns. For the purposes of determining the uniqueness of primary key values, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs. If an INSERT or UPDATE statement attempts to modify the table content so that two or more rows have identical primary key values, that is a constraint violation.
>
> According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table or the column is declared NOT NULL, SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column. SQLite could be fixed to conform to the standard, but doing so might break legacy applications. Hence, it has been decided to merely document the fact that SQLite allowing NULLs in most PRIMARY KEY columns.

Since NULL in a PK is against SQL, it seems moot what SQLite then chooses to do when constraining and manipulating tables with NULLs in a PK. But it uses the usual SQL interpretation that NULL is not equal to NULL for purposes of UNIQUE. This is like when you declare a column set UNIQUE NULL. So as a constraint, SQLite PK is a synonym for UNIQUE instead of UNIQUE NOT NULL.

> A UNIQUE constraint is similar to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, except that a single table may have any number of UNIQUE constraints. For each UNIQUE constraint on the table, each row must contain a unique combination of values in the columns identified by the UNIQUE constraint. For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs.

Comment: Good point, but then I thought `NOT NULL` was supposed to enforce something. It's not just a glorified comment, right? Why is SQLite not rejecting it?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you are trying to say in your comment. The quote says very clearly that allowing NULL was a bug that they decided to keep supporting, and *explicit* additional NOT NULL works. What is the "it" in "Why is SQLite not rejecting it?" The *duplicate* rows with NULL? My answer and the quote say very clearly that they decided to use SQL 3VL "equality" [sic] for uniqueness, and NULL = NULL is false, so they're not equal, so each is unique.

Comment: Oh, I was just responding to your statement that "you should not put NULL in them" and "it seems moot what SQLite chooses to do"; I was just saying it's most definitely not moot---the lack of enforcement is a pretty blatant violation of SQL. It's not like it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Re moot, I meant *given* that they allow NULL in PKs, it's moot "what SQLite chooses to do when operating on tables with NULLs in primary key columns". There's no point it trying to make sense once you've started to not make sense. Declare explicit NOT NULL and don't put NULLs in PKs.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite, like many other SQL databases, considers two `NULL`s as different values for the purposes of uniqueness (partially because, in SQL, `NULL == NULL` is false).

I don't believe there is a way to alter this behavior. As a workaround, you can use an empty string in column `b` as "no value".

Comment: This is no reason, since SQL does not allow NULL in PKs.

Comment: @philipxy SQLite does allow NULLs in PKs, and this question is about SQLite, so I see no reason not to answer with respect to SQLite's features.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment has to do with my comment. It doesn't dispute the fact or relevance of SQLite allowing it. I am saying that how null comparison works is not a justification for the behaviour. See my answer & comments there.